# Should I switch over to UNIX?

Tags: unix

I used Windows 98 second edition. I loved it. Then I started on Windows XP Pro 32 bits. I found it reliable and easy to work with.
Now I get a message that Ms will not support Windows XP Pro, from April 8.
I tried Windows 8. I found it extremely cumbersome and very wasteful.
I am bit tired of Ms manipulation of its customers dumping on them unnecessary packages.Furthermore, I am really sick and tired of Viruses, Malwares and sheer audacity of these miscreant to embed their nefarious package without even warning me.

Should I invest my time learning Windows 8 or simply switch over to Unix?
Regards
Sal

NB I am a retired person age 72.

Comment: Have you tried 7?

Comment: Your complaint makes no sense.  Windows XP is 13 years old.  You using Windows 7 is not manipulation on Microsoft's part.  There is no other operating system in the history of operating systems that was supported for **13 years** like Windows XP was.  I hate to blame the user but, most of the time if a system is infected with malware, its the fault of the user.  Linux and OS X have malware problems if you ignore good security procedures.  Additional 99% of Windows problems can be avoided by not running as an `Administrator`.

Comment: I'd shoot for Linux (e.g. Ubuntu, CentOS, etc) over a UNIX OS (e.g. FreeBSD) for a home machine.

Comment: This is all opinion-based, and should/will be closed soon.  IMO, use Windows 8.1.  :)

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of very usable Linux distributions out there, which are easy to understand for someone who even only has some basic understanding of computers (since you're obviously using computers for at least one and a half decade, you should have more than enough ;)

For »beginners« (regarding Linux) I'd recommend [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.org), which is basically an Ubuntu with a more familiar user interface.

In the first place you would not even have to »switch« in one go, but you could easygoingly take a look around by installing some distribution in a virtual machine first (have a look at  [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org)) or just burning an installation disc and booting into »Live Mode« (at least Ubuntu and Linux Mint provide one).

**<Edit>**
Even if you *later* decide to install it on »bare metal« you won't have to delete your Windows completely, either; Linux can comfortably be installed alongside an existing Windows installation.
**</Edit>**

I think you would get along with it very well, so don't be afraid to give it a try.

Comment: While the idea is great, suggesting someone with no experience with Linux go ahead and install it alongside windows without mentioning that he should back all of his data up first is irresponsible :\   It might be trivial for me or you to do without issue, but it can be quite daunting otherwise.

Comment: The actual emphasis should've been on the first two variants (VM and/or Live CD).  Added the missing word to make it clear.